# O que é Text= Resources de um botão dxe?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-basic-6

Quero saber o que é esse trecho que código de um botão dxe:ASPxButton, e como funciona?

```
Text="<%$ Resources: Textos, BotaoLogin %>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Olá, está utilizando resources para definir o texto.

Isto é utilizado geralmente para criar aplicações com mais de um idioma

Segue artigos que podem te ajudar.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fw69ke6f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

http://www.macoratti.net/aspn_mla.htm

http://www.dev.mayogax.me/internacionalizacao-de-sites-asp-net